# Getting Internal Server Error when using RCurl with API's in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I am relatively new to API's and all that stuff, but I try to collect data through an API for http://my.wirelesstag.net through `R` with the `RCurl` package. Yesterday it worked just fine, but today I get an following error: `Error: Internal Server Error`. I suspect that the error occurs because I don't close the previous connection—maybe I am wrong. Anyway, any help to get the script working is appreciated.

My script for retrieving the data is as below (the example is unfortunately not a MWE as I keep the login information for myself):

```
library(RCurl)
library(jsonlite)

# Acccept cookies
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(cookiejar = "/tmp/cookies.txt", curl = curl, verbose = T)


# Account information ----------------------------------------------


# Parameter list
prm <- list(baseUrl = "https://my.wirelesstag.net",
            username = "user@user.com",
            password = "password")


# Sign-in ----------------------------------------------------------


# Sign-in
invisible(
    postForm(paste0(prm$baseUrl, "/ethAccount.asmx/SignIn"),
             curl = curl,
             .opts = list(
                 postfields = toJSON(list(
                     email = prm$username,
                     password = prm$password
                 )),
                 httpheader = c("Content-Type" = "application/json")
             ))
)
```

The entire log when executing `postForm()` is:

```
*   Trying 130.211.169.89...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to my.wirelesstag.net (130.211.169.89) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=my.wirelesstag.net
*  start date: Jul 20 00:00:00 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Oct 19 23:59:59 2019 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my.wirelesstag.net" matched cert's "my.wirelesstag.net"
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /ethAccount.asmx/SignIn HTTP/1.1
Host: my.wirelesstag.net
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 58

* upload completely sent off: 58 out of 58 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< jsonerror: true
< Date: Thu, 01 Mar 2018 11:27:33 GMT
< Content-Length: 1019
< 
* Connection #0 to host my.wirelesstag.net left intact
Error: Internal Server Error
```

Comment: If it worked yesterday and you literally changed _nothing_ in your script, then I would suspect first your internet connection, and second the service itself, which might be down now.  Have you checked both of these?

Comment: Hmm. My internet connection seems to work fine. So maybe, it is just a unstable API.